# Heatmap on top of gray-scale images in python

Tags: python, visualization, package

Simple and straightforward question, I need to plot a heatmap on top of a gray scale image in python, like the one below.

[image: The color-scale is shown on top of the gray scale image. Where the color-scale is not defined, the image is zero]

I come from MATLAB. There I would simply generate the probability map, pass it though a colormap and plug the result in the gray scalar picture.

I could do the same in python, though I feel like is not the most "pythonic" way to proceed (with numpy). You know any particular package that handles this kind of visualization?

Comment: Take a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)